# OSD with ConfigMgr across subnets?

Tags: networking, pxe-boot, sccm

I am trying to deploy a system image from one subnet to another.  Subnet A contains the SCCM server.  Subnet B contains the workstation that I want to build.  Subnet B contains a DHCP server with a scope configured to service the workstations.  How would I configure the DHCP server so that it tells the workstations to look at the SCCM server on Subnet A as its bootserver?

In addition, Subnet A and Subnet B are separate domains.

Comment: so subnet B has a DHCP server and is in another domain then the sccm server, what domain is the DHCP server authorized to issue ip's to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need an IP Helper address added to your router with the PXE server and/or DHCP server.  That way, when the computer on subB sends a broadcast PXE request, the router knows to allow/forward that on to subA.

Comment: Just to clarify, if both the PXE and DHCP servers are on a different subnet from the client, you will need a separate ip helper-address entry for each server, since both PXE and DHCP do not normally broadcast ouside a subnet.